select multiple disabled not showing in mobile
I have a:
<select multiple disabled>
  <option selected>opt1</option>
  <option selected>opt2</option>
  <option>opt3</option>
</select>

On desktop (Chrome), it shows OK (a list with first two selected)
On mobile (Chrome browser), it shows one line written ("2 selected") but because it's disabled, user can't click and see the two options selected.
Seems a bug in the mobile browser, because they could show the two selected and not let to change them.
How to fix that? I need a select that is multiple and options can't be changed.
Tried to use size='3' but doesn't work either.

Please try this trick it works on Chrome on latest iOS 17.5.1
https://jsfiddle.net/Anthony_S2024/no6qpms3/15/
 <select name="cars" id="cars" multiple  style="width:200px;">
  <option value="volvo" selected disabled>Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab" selected disabled>Saab</option>
  <option value="opel" disabled>Opel</option>
  <option value="audi" disabled>Audi</option>
 </select>


note the ... next to the select on mobile device that will expand the select control. Sorry, but I don't have an android phone to test.
Thanks
